# Append to array in json file from another json file with "jq"

Tags: json, bash, logging, jq, jsonlines

i have a file "stats.json" with the following initial structure"

```
[{
"price": 66.55,
"created": "2018-02-24T14:32:57"
}]
```

With a bash/curl script i take every 10 minutes data from an api and save it to "temp.json"

```
{
"price": 88.55,
"created": "2018-02-24T15:32:57"
}
```

I would like to merge the temp.json (which is updated every 10min) and to fill the stats.json file. I tried to do it with "jq" but without success.

Comment: This is going to get slower and more expensive the longer your file is (and moreover, constant rewriting of old data increases risk of corruption or loss); I *strongly* suggest taking peak's advice, and changing to a format you can append to as a constant-time operation.

Comment: thanks for the heads up, the data older than 7-14 days will be purged.

Answer (score 4):

One way to add the item in temp.obj to the array in stats.json:

```
jq —-slurpfile temp temp.obj '. + $temp' stats.json
```

Another way:

```
jq —s '.[0] + [.[1]]' stats.json temp.json
```

(If you want to overwrite stats.json, then I’d suggest using `sponge` as illustrated below.)

However, if at all possible, it would almost certainly be better to maintain stats.json as a log file in JSONL format: http://jsonlines.org/

That is, each object in temp.json would be appended as a single line to stats.json:

```
jq -c temp.json >> stats.json
```

This of course assumes that stats.json is initially empty or already in the JSONL format.  To convert your existing stats.json to JSONL, you could do something like this:

```
cp -p stats.json stats.json.bak

jq -c .[] stats.json | sponge stats.json
```

Comment: jq -c temp.json >> stats.json
Is there a way to add an comma after the input?

Comment: Yes, of course, but why would you want to?  That would break everything. m The idea is to use line breaks as the "delimiter".

Comment: @peak I guess I do understand @nelasx; I guess we both failed to understand (him and I) is that a file full of objects will also work as a file that has [{object},{object}]

but your post made me aware of this possibility! tks